# Apache Wicket - externalizing components

Tags: java, rest, wicket, wicket-6, microservices

As our Apache Wicket 6 application is growing and growing, we are thinking about externalizing components to some kind of UI microservice. Therefore we would like to build a Wicket application that can deliver the following content as JSON (or XML):

```
{
    "js": 
        [
           "/external-component/question/general.js",
           "/external-component/question/input.js"
        ],
    "style":
        [
           "/external-component/question/general.css",
           "/external-component/question/input.css"
        ],
    "content": "/external-component/question/input.html"
}
```

Calling /external-component/question/input.html would then render the component and deliver something like this:

```
<div>
    <form>
        Please ask your question: 
        <input type="text" /> 
        <input type="submit" /> 
    </form>
</div>
```

Of course, it's important that the first call doesn't render the component on the fly, as this may take a while (backend calls).

We tried our best, but couldn't deliver the JS scripts Wicket needs without rendering the component.

Has anybody tried something similar or has an idea how to do this?

Comment: What exactly is the end goal? How would you use the rendered snippet of HTML from such component?

Comment: Goal is to have a loose coupling, so one application can orchestrate components from many smaller applications, resulting in simpler and clearer applications with lower building times. The HTML would be included via getStringValue(T object) in a component that just handles external components by including the js and css files via renderHead(IHeaderResponse response).

Comment: Why don't you create Maven/Gradle/SBT/... modules for the components? Loading (the output of) each component via HTTP seems like overkill to me. Once you separate the reusable components in their own module it will come as pre-build dependency to the application module(s) and won't add to their build time.

Comment: Thanks for your help @martin-g! Modularizing seems to be a good way as well :)